# How does the LEGO Group transport its products? Can LEGO bricks be recycled?

Tags: transport

1.
Hello, I am doing research on LEGO for a school project.  I want to know where are the LEGO factories?  How do the LEGO products get from factories to the stores around the world?  What shipping routes?  What kind of cargo ships, how much LEGO product is being transported per ship?  How many times do ships get sent?  What is the work force that are in charge and working to get the LEGO bricks to where they need to be?  After it gets to land how do they transport it?  How much fuel is used?

2.
I have found that you are able to break down LEGO bricks that do not fit the high standards (18 to a million) and have it back to its ABS granules for re-use.  I really like that the LEGO Group is recycling, but will they allow people to give used LEGO bricks that they have back to the company to make new LEGO products? What can we do to recycle LEGO bricks if we won't use it anymore?  What are you doing or plan to do in order to make LEGO products recyclable in a way that is easy for the consumer?

Comment: Per (2): http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/1261/are-lego-bricks-recyclable

Comment: Two comments: First, this is website is not affiliated with the Lego company. Second, please separate your two questions into different posts.

Comment: Note that (1) is probably unanswerable, as no one here works for LEGO, or is privy to their logistics decisions. Best to contact LEGO directly.

Comment: I highly recommend you [contact LEGO directly](https://wwwsecure.us.lego.com/en-us/service). LEGO are fairly secretive about their manufacturing and distribution setup, so I wouldn't expect them to go too far into the specifics.